# Наложение водяного знака на видео

Tags: android, opengl, видео, gles2.0

Я создал приложение, которое записывает видео с камеры без звука в течение 10 секунд. Вот часть кода:

```
...
MediaCodec mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
mMediaCodec.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
Surface mSurface = mMediaCodec.createInputSurface();
EGLDisplay mEGLDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
int[] e = new int[2];
EGL14.eglInitialize(mEGLDisplay, e, 0, e, 1);
EGLConfig[] mEGLConfig = new EGLConfig[1];
EGL14.eglChooseConfig(mEGLDisplay, new int[]{EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8, EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8, EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8, EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8, EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, 12610, 1, EGL14.EGL_NONE}, 0, mEGLConfig, 0, 1, new int[1], 0);
EGLContext mEGLContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(mEGLDisplay, mEGLConfig[0], EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, new int[]{EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL14.EGL_NONE}, 0);
EGLSurface mEGLSurface = EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLConfig[0], mSurface, new int[]{EGL14.EGL_NONE}, 0);
mMediaCodec.start();
MediaMuxer mMediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ipcamera.mp4").getPath(), OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, mEGLSurface, mEGLContext);
FloatBuffer mFloatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(80).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
mFloatBuffer.put(new float[]{-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}).position(0);
float[] sm1 = new float[16], sm2 = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(sm1, 0);
int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram(), f = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER), params[] = new int[1];
GLES20.glShaderSource(f, "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
        "   vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
        "}\n");
GLES20.glCompileShader(f);
GLES20.glGetShaderiv(f, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, params, 0);
GLES20.glAttachShader(program, f);
GLES20.glShaderSource(f = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER), "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "}\n");
GLES20.glCompileShader(f);
GLES20.glGetShaderiv(f, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, params, 0);
GLES20.glAttachShader(program, f);
GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, params, 0);
if (params[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
int maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "aPosition"), maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "aTextureCoord"), muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uMVPMatrix"), muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uSTMatrix"), texName[] = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texName, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texName[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
(mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texName[0])).setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
mCamera.startPreview();
long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
BufferInfo mBufferInfo = new BufferInfo();
boolean b = true;
int c, d = 0;
do {
    synchronized (VideoRecording.this.b) {
        if (!VideoRecording.this.b) continue; else VideoRecording.this.b = false;
    }
    mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
    mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(sm1);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texName[0]);
    mFloatBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 20, mFloatBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    mFloatBuffer.position(3);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 20, mFloatBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(sm2, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, sm2, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, sm1, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
    EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
    if (!(b = System.currentTimeMillis() - a < 10000)) mMediaCodec.signalEndOfInputStream();
    while ((c = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, 10000)) != MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER || !b) {
        if (c == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            d = mMediaMuxer.addTrack(mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat());
            mMediaMuxer.start();
        } else if (c >= 0) {
            if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) mBufferInfo.size = 0; else mMediaMuxer.writeSampleData(d, (ByteBuffer) mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers()[c].position(mBufferInfo.offset).limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size), mBufferInfo);
            mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(c, false);
            if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) break;
        }
    }
} while (b);
mMediaCodec.stop();
mMediaCodec.release();
EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
EGL14.eglDestroySurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
EGL14.eglDestroyContext(mEGLDisplay, mEGLContext);
EGL14.eglReleaseThread();
EGL14.eglTerminate(mEGLDisplay);
mSurface.release();
...
@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    synchronized (VideoRecording.this.b) {
        VideoRecording.this.b = true;
    }
}
```

Я практически импортировал весь код известного почти всем [CameraToMpegTest.java](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt) и постарался максимально его для себя упростить, переместив множество кодов в один метод (часть кода которого собственно и представил выше).

Я сразу скажу, что являюсь программистом Java с опытом 3 года, однако пользуюсь библиотеками OpenGL Android впервые. Я уже читал множество туториалов на эту тему, однако мало информации было связано с видеозаписью при помощи `MediaMuxer` и библиотеками OpenGL. Разве что, проект Grafika содержит полезное.

Как можно наложить водяной знак (пусть им будет, к примеру, картинка `R.mipmap.ic_launcher`) на видео справа снизу? В интернете нашёл не много полезной информации, в одной из статей был представлен следующий код наложения водяного знака:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

//Generate one texture pointer...
gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
//...and bind it to our array
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

//Create Nearest Filtered Texture
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

//Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

//Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

//Clean up
bitmap.recycle();
```

Однако у меня нет идей, куда конкретно этот код поместить. Я пробовал помещать его практически во всевозможные места кода, однако это ни к чему не приводило, либо приводило к повреждению видеозаписи. Также, в одном из вопросов англоязычного форума stackoverflow (ссылку на вопрос не сохранил) утверждали, что нужно создавать две программы GLES20... Таким образом, 6 дней назад я попал в тупик и до сих пор не сдвинулся с мёртвой точки - водяной знак на моём видео критично нужен.

**Подскажите корректный код** наложения водяного знака на видео. Куда его поместить в моём случае? Может и вовсе это можно сделать без использования OpenGL так, чтобы запись видео была по-прежнему при помощи `MediaMuxer` и `MediaCodec`?

---

*Дополнительная информация.*

**Различные библиотеки, подобные FFMPEG, не предлагайте. Нужно наложить водяной знак встроенными в Android средствами.**

**Минимальная требуемая версия API у моего приложения будет не выше 18 (Android 4.3.1).**

Comment: Вроде тут понятно описано где и когда что делать - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231245/2649222

Comment: @ei-grad, как раз непонятно. План выглядит нормально, однако вовсе не ясно, как будет выглядеть программный код. Как я *выдерну фрейм* из `SurfaceTexture`? Ну, **допустим,** я получил эту *фрейм* в виде `Bitmap`, нарисовал на ней водяной знак. Каким образом я её отправлю в `MediaCodec`? Если Вам все инструкции понятны в этом ответе, пожалуйста, подскажите программный код.

Comment: Судя по всему вам необходимо в шейдеры передать 2 текстуры: кадр(который вы передаёте) и картику водяного знака и позицию водяного знака (или его текстурыне координаты, как удобно) и в пиксельном шейдере их смешать.

Comment: Либо отдельным проходом по верх видео нарисовать прямоугольник в нужном углу с текстурой водяного знака.

Comment: Забирать кадр в CPU и там накладывать водяной знак выглядит как не самое оптимальное по производительности решение.

Comment: @Unick, рисовать на `Canvas` - хуже. Я высчитал среднее общее время рисования (конвертация NV21 *фрейм* в JPEG байты, затем их в `Bitmap`, и т.д., и затем обратно в NV21) занимает 120 миллисекунд. Это просто сумасшедшее длительное время: представляете, у моего видео должно быть 25-30 fps, а будет 5-8 fps. Так что, вероятно надо всё-таки один раз *загрузить* водяной знак в OpenGL и на каждой *фрейм* его рисовать, не так ли?

Comment: @Unick, вот если вы со мной согласны, то получается, что мой вопрос заключается в том, как такое реализовать на деле, а не на словах.

Comment: "Так что, вероятно надо всё-таки один раз загрузить водяной знак в OpenGL и на каждой фрейм его рисовать, не так ли?" да так. Вы же умеете отрисовывать фрейм (glDrawArrays), водяной знак это тоже самое, только текстура другая и позиция с размерам другие.

Comment: @Unick, можете туториалы для Android подсказать, где есть информация о рисовании, указании позиции текстуры и её размеров, и т.п.? На Android Open Source Project всё в словах, в других статьях крайне мало кода.

Comment: 2 недели ищу, пока не сдвинулся с мёртвой точки

Comment: я так быстро не нашёл. Я могу только примерно написать как надо делать, т.к. на Андроиде с OpenGL не работал.

Comment: @Unick, ну напишите так. Напишите ответ как это можно сделать, только получается не на Android. Я засчитаю ответ, если, переписав код на Android, всё получится.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему после отрисовки кадра необходимо отрисовать водяной знак, код будет выглядить примерно так:

```
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); // Ваш старый вызов

float[] watermarkSM = new float[16]; // Своя матрица для watermark-а
Matrix.setIdentityM(watermarkSM, 0);
Matrix.setScaleM(watermarkSM, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25); // делаем водяной знак меньше, пусть на четверть
// также можно сдвинуть методом setTranslateM, хотя по названию не уверен.
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texNameWatermark);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, watermarkSM, 0);
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); // Рисуем watermark

// Ваш старый код.
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
```

Т.е. мы устанавливаем текстуру watermark-а, настраиваем его размер и позицию и рисуем его также как кадр. Если вы захотите сделать его полупрозрачным, то текстура должна иметь альфаканал и настроить блендинг. Вставить этот год перед отрисовкой watermark-а.

```
GLES20.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
GLES20.BlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
```